# Facebook js api: share a post to a friend's wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

i really hope, someone can point me into the right direction. I am ordered to write a drawing game for facebook. The concept is, the one, applying for a win, references a friend for the prize (the player won't win anything, just his friend).
The customer want's a Post on both Walls/Timelines. AFAIK it's not possible to post on the friend's wall. Right now i am as far, that the App posts on the wall, of whom is playing.

Is it possible to share this Post to his friend without any Dialog or represent to the friend, that he is applied for a prize?
The customer wants that this doesn't use any share/feed dialog.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _“The customer want's a Post on both Walls/Timelines.”_ – tell him that’s __spam__. Facebook Platform Policies: [_“You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.”_](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration)

Comment: I've read the update post aswell. Beside there shouldn't be anything more than just a mention on the friends wall. Like if some of your friends, mark you on his photos.
--edit: the one about to win a prize should be informed, that he is. Shouldn't he?

Comment: That would be a case for Open Graph actions then.

Comment: found a solution but cant post it yet. Keyword for such actions is tagging with some difficulties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the second day of digging in i came to a solution. As the Open Graph Api mentions, the keyword is tagging BUT, the META tags mentioned in the documentation didn't work for me in any way.
I came up to use an Page ID for the place field and used the friends ID as value for the tags field. Once the friend is tagged with the post, he will see the same post on his own timeline.
Here's a snippet:

```
facebook.api('/me/feed', 'POST', {
        'message' : userdata.name + ' hat für ' + frienddata.name + ' einen ' + $('span.buggyname').html() + '...',
        'picture' : 'some picture URL',
        'link' : 'URL to see game result',
        'name' : 'our awesome game',
        'place' : 'pageid of customer',
        'tags' : frienddata.id
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```